# Null check operator used on a null value The relevant error-causing widget was ListView

Tags: php, flutter, listview, null

I am listing out some data from database, but I am getting error as Null Check Operator is used on null value. I am attaching my code here. I am using flutter for frontend and php for backend. My backend code is working fine. I got the required results while testing in postman. Any hep would be deeply appreciated. I removed all the possible "!" in the code, as it raises null check. Also, I removed checking whether the list is empty. Even then I am getting the same error.

```
class L_N_Maintenance extends StatefulWidget {
  const L_N_Maintenance({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _L_N_MaintenanceState createState() => _L_N_MaintenanceState();
}

class _L_N_MaintenanceState extends State<L_N_Maintenance> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cprController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();

  Future getList() async {
    // var url = "/view_listed_ flat.php";
    // var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(ApiConstant.baseUrl + url));
    // return json.decode(response.body);

    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var useremail = preferences.getString('useremail') ?? "Not found";

    debugPrint(useremail);
    // debugPrint(appusertype);

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    const key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Charset': 'utf-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "email": useremail,
    };
    //var bodyEncoded = json.encode(body);
    var bodyEncoded = body.keys.map((key) => "$key=${body[key]}").join("&");
    print(bodyEncoded);
    var url = "/maintenance/owner_list.php";
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiConstant.baseUrl + url),
        headers: headers,
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
        body: bodyEncoded);
    print(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 64, 122),
        title: const Text(
          'MAINTENANCE REQUEST',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.zero,
            child: Text(
              "طلب صيانة",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
            )),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/building.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getList(),
                builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List list = snapshot.data as List;
                    //print(list);
                    if (list.isEmpty) {
                      //print("yeah");
                      return const Center(
                          child: Card(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                child: Text('No Requests'),
                              )));
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          //print(list);
                          //if (list.isNotEmpty) {
                          return Stack(
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    //var call=data[index]['link'],
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const L_N_MaintenanceDetails()),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Card(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        //Image(image: AssetImage ("assets/building.jpg")),
                                        Container(
                                          width: 90,
                                          height: 70,
                                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/building.jpg"),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                        // Icon(data[index]['icon'],color:Colors.white,size: 30,),
                                        // Text('${data[index]['eng']}',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                        // Text('${data[index]['ar']}',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                        // // ('${data[index]['eng']}'=='Add New Tenant')?():(Text("yeah"))
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              10, 0, 0, 0),
                                          child: Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'Problem :',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                                          fontSize: 14),
                                                    ),
                                                    Flexible(
                                                        child: Text(list[index]
                                                            ['problem']))
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'Property:',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                                          fontSize: 14),
                                                    ),
                                                    Flexible(
                                                        child: Text(list[index]
                                                            ['prop_name']))
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'Location:',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                                          fontSize: 14),
                                                    ),
                                                    Flexible(
                                                        child: Text(list[index]
                                                            ['location']))
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'Priority:',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                                          fontSize: 14),
                                                    ),
                                                    Flexible(
                                                        child: Text(list[index]
                                                            ['priority']))
                                                  ],
                                                )
                                              ]),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 0,
                                right: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 120,
                                  height: 25,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                  child: const Center(
                                      child: const Text(
                                    'Progress',
                                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                          // //} else {
                          //   return const Center(
                          //     child: Card(
                          //         color: Colors.white,
                          //         child: Padding(
                          //           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          //           child: Text('No Requests'),
                          //         )),
                          //   );
                          // }
                        }));
                  } else {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                }))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @athlas asked: Can you please provide the output console log?

Comment: do you get data on `print(list);`

Comment: yes, i get my data on printing

Comment: Can you try string format like `Text("${list[index]['problem']}"))`

Comment: Still same errors

Comment: try to use the format for all Text widget or comment them

Comment: I used it for every Text widget, but got error

Comment: Do you get error after commenting all components on itemBuilder and try to provide dataType on FutureBuilder

Comment: please make all field nullable before do any operation. suppose you getting Problem from db. assign the variable into String variable then do operation like(String? problemData =list[index]['problem']); then set data on TextField like Text(problemData ??'');